# How to select element with Thymeleaf attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, thymeleaf

I have an HTML page with the following element:

```
<input type="text" th:field="*{recipientName}"/>
```

I want to select this element by attribute with jQuery function, like this:

```
$("[th:field='*{recipientName}']")
```

However, I get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [th:field='*{recipientName}']
```

How can I select this element and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: See the update at the very end of my answer below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem is that the colon : is not valid in an attribute name, so the selector fails to return anything. If you're unable to change the name of the selector (i.e. if the colon is a Thymeleaf requirement), you will have to add an alternate identifier.

Maybe put the whole field name and value into a data- attribute? e.g.

`<input type="text" data-somevar="th:field=*{recipientName}" th:field="*{recipientName}"/>`

And then select it like this:

`$("[data-somevar='th:field=*{recipientName}']");`

**Update:** I have had a play around with it and it appears it is possible if you escape the colon when passing it to jQuery, so this should work:

`$("[th\\:field='*{recipientName}']");`

[Codepen example.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jaEyoW)

I'll leave the previous answer/explanation in case anyone else finds it useful.